# How to do a partial prefix search in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a Phonebook program that I can search through with a partial prefix. The program goes through a .txt file and asks the user who they want to search for. Example of .txt file:

```
Captain-Crunch 123-456-7890
Silly-Goose 234-456-7891
Some-Dude 890-234-5679
```

etc

I want to be able to search 'S' and it will give me the first instance it finds, so "Silly-Goose 234-456-7891" for example. The code I have now does this, but let's say I enter 'G', it will also return "Silly-Goose 234-456-7891". I just want the partial prefix search to match up with the first letters, and not search for just *any* instance for what I searched.

Current code:

```cpp
    string search;
    string line, name, number;
    int count = 0;
    size_t found;
    
   
    cout << "Please enter person to search for: ";
    cin >> search;
    
    
    if(search == "."){
        cout << "Thank you for using this program!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        inFile >> name;
        inFile >> number;
        found = name.find(search);
        if (found = !string::npos){
            cout << name << " " << number << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want only results from the start, why not check if `found == 0`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he messed up this part more than that. He should use `std::istringstream line_stream{line};`.

Comment: Whoever assigned this may be expecting you to teach yourself about the Trie data structure.

Comment: @user4581301 Its not a Trie data structure thing, it supposed to be about recursion, but this isn't supposed to be the recursive part of it. Right now, we're just focused on doing a basic search function.

Comment: For a cheap hack, `found = !string::npos` is goofy and too permissive even when fixed. `found != string::npos` will allow the search term to be found anywhere. You want it to exist only at the beginning. `found == 0` ought to do that.

Comment: Because a Trie is a tree structure, it lends itself well to a recursive solution. So long as the Trie doesn't get big enough to overflow the stack during traversal, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're searching for `name.find(search) != string::npos` which means "is name in search".

According to [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) string::find "returns the position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found". What does that mean? Basicly **it returns the offset of the substring** in the string you searched for. In your case, you want that result to be 0 (your character would be at the start of the chain).

So, as @NathanOliver already suggested, the solution would be to replace

```
if(found != string::npos)
```

by

```
if(found == 0)
```

Comment: @user4581301 I'm confused on what my bugs are? After this solution my program is working as intended.

Comment: @AlexanderSwan `while (getline(inFile, line))` discards a line of the file on every iteration of the loop  without checking its contents. If you are not seeing the effects of this in your testing, your tests are not complete.

Answer (score 0):

C++20 added [`std::basic_string::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) for this purpose:

```
if (name.starts_with(search)) {
  // found
}
```

*Note that [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a `std::basic_string`.*

-> **[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1dM5ds)**